# Exclude # ed columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a scenario in MS Excel as below:

I need only the un commented / non-hashed rows listed automatically in same sheet.

[image]

Comment: Do you want a vba macro or in-sheet function?

Comment: Um, sure, go ahead. Unless you have a question, have a problem getting those and show your attempt, go ahead.

Comment: Portland Runner , in-sheet function would be better as 100's of columns need to be listed. If no option okay with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the data is in column A from A1 thru A20.
In B1 enter:
**=IF(LEFT(A1,1)<>"#",1,"")**
In B2 enter:
**=IF(LEFT(A2,1)<>"#",MAX($B$1:B1)+1,"")**  and copy down
In C1 enter:
**=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$20,MATCH(ROW(),$B$1:$B$20,0),1),"")**  and copy down

For example:
[image]

Comment: Gary's Student
 Thanks Gary simplest solution works good for num and alpha values. Thanks again